# New Visualforce Tab- Available in Touch?

Tags: visualforce, mobile, touch, html5

I'm trying to show a Visualforce Tab on the Salesforce Touch app for the iPad but havent been able to. I've enabled all the settings in the Salesforce Touch options in the setup menu plus made sure both my page and the VF tab were set to be available in touch.

If it were be the case that the VF tab is not yet available for the native iPad version of the app how do I come across the HTML 5 one?

Thanks for your time

Edit: added pictures to show the current settings in the org for the tab, VF page and the SF touch settings

[image: SF Touch Settings]

[image: VF Page]

[image: Tab Settings]

Comment: i think you need to download newer version of app from appstore and try with new version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your Tab added to an Application that's visible in Touch?

For example, visit the "Customize my Tabs" link for the Sales application and add your VF tab to the list.

FWIW, I got this working on the HTML5 version of Touch on an iPad

Comment: Dave, I see the tabs in the Selected Tabs list of my app (I'm trying to use a custom app but I'm also testing on the Sales app) but still no avail, how did you get to the HTML5 version of Touch?

Comment: It seems to flip into 'Touch' when you log in using the standard login page (login.salesforce.com) on the iPad .. if you want to go back to the desktop mode, there's an option inside the Touch app to 'Turn off Touch'. Once you turn it off, you can turn it back on with 'Go to Touch' in the footer

Comment: Thanks Dave, yeah apparently the VF tabs are only available in the HTML5 version of the application. They don't show up on the native iPad application.

Comment: As an FYI, VF Tabs seem to show up in the iPad application now

Answer (score 1):

VF tabs only appear on the HTML5 version of the Touch app. The native iPad app does not include them yet.